# How to change the canvas FillMode in Delphi (FireMonkey)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Please, look at this TPathData in FireMonkey which holds two subpaths: the first one an external rectangle and the second another rectangle inside the first one:

```
TmpPathData := TPathData.Create;
TmpPathData.Data := 'M1,1 H100 V100 H1 Z   M30,30 H70 V70 H30 Z';
```

Then I want to fill this path on a Bitmap so:

```
TmpBmp := TBitmap.Create(200, 200);
TmpBmp.Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
TmpBmp.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blue;
TmpBmp.Canvas.BeginScene;
TmpBmp.Canvas.FillPath(TmpPathData, 1);
TmpBmp.Canvas.EndScene;
```

The result is this:

[image]

but I want to get this:

[image]

so: **How can I change the FillMode in FireMonkey from "Alternate" to "Winding".**

Note: I'm using Delphi 10.3.3

Comment: Why are you using two rectangles and not just one?

Comment: @Olivier I just explained the problem in a simple way. In the real world I have a long list of rectangles in the path data. Some of them overlapping others so I want to Fill all the rectangles but with no "holes".

Comment: I assume it is the same effect, that in Windows GDI is referred to as `PolyFillMode` which can be set with `SetPolyFillMode()` to either `Alternate` or `Winding`. Now in `Firemonkey` I did not find anything similar. Maybe `FMX` only has `Alternate`. To overcome the problem declare a path according to the outer rectangle only, to be used when you want to fill the whole rectangle.

Comment: @TomBrunberg not all rectangles are perfectly inside others, some of them are just partially inside. Also, I am trying to speed up a routine drawing in one shot all rectangles so I dont want to waste time finding the outer rectangles.

Comment: Yes Delmo, I do understand from your comment to Olivier that this is only a simplified example to demonstrate the issue. As I said in my previous comment, there doesn't seem to be a way to mimic the Win GDI `PolyFillMode` named `Winding` which would do what you want. I searched for a solution in my Delphi XE7, but found no way to solve it. Search sources in your Delphi 10.3.3 if there are anything concerning `FillMode`, `PolyFillMode` or such. Otherwise you just have to find out whatever works for you somehow. Sorry but I can't help you further with this.

Comment: Thanks @TomBrunberg, I really appreciate your concern in order to help me finding a solution! I did exactly what you suggest, I check the source code searching some way to change the FillMode but I didn't find anything valuable so I posted this question just in case anyone else had find something that I couldn't. Conclusion: It looks that there is no way to change FillMode. However it's a bit odd to me because the underlaying APIs (GDI+, DirectX) allow to change it (even SVG spec allow it throught "fill-rule" attribute), so why Delphi don't?

Comment: I was able to get winding fill mode working in FMX by copying FMX.Canvas.D2D.pas locally and adding Path.SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING); in TCanvasD2D.CreatePathGeometry just after Geometry.Open(Path). It works but modifying Delphi code is a horrible solution. You would also need to make similar changes in FMX.Canvas.GDI.pas and FMX.Canvas.GPU.pas.